# Connecting filled curves producing a gap at the connection

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

I want to make a problem about hydrostatic pressure and density in a open tube. For that I want to fill up a tube with different liquids. I've managed to produce this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=10, xmin=0,xmax=5]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{1/4/A, 1/2/B, 2/1/C, 3/2/D, 3/6/E};
\tkzLabelPoints[right](A,B,D,E);
\tkzLabelPoints[below](C);
\draw[thick,double=brown!40,double distance=5pt,draw=black]  plot[smooth, tension=0.3] coordinates {(A) (B) (C) (D) (E)};
\draw[thick,double=blue!40,double distance=5pt,draw=black]  plot[smooth, tension=0.5] coordinates {(1,6)  (A)};
\draw[thick,double=white,double distance=5pt,draw=black]  plot[smooth, tension=0.5] coordinates {(1,8)  (1,6)};
\draw[thick,double=white,double distance=5pt,draw=black]  plot[smooth, tension=0.5] coordinates {(E)  (3,8)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which results in this:

[image]

First of all, the letters are just for explanation of the problem.
If you look closely at A and E, there is a gap. This is caused because the curve A-B-C-D-E doesn't exactly do what I want:

1. The lines from A to B and from E to D straight.
2. The curve from B to D (over C) should be a half circle (so I think it should be done without the point C).

(The lines on top of tube are a screenshot error, so no problem there.) How could I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label={[xshift=1mm]right:A}] (A) at (1,4);
\coordinate[label={[xshift=1mm]right:B}] (B) at (1,2);
\coordinate[label={[yshift=-1mm]below:C}] (C) at (2,1);
\coordinate[label={[xshift=1mm]right:D}] (D) at (3,2);
\coordinate[label={[xshift=1mm]right:E}] (E) at (3,6);
\draw[thick,double=blue!40,double distance=5pt,draw=black] (A)-- +(0,2)coordinate (aa);
\draw[thick,double=white,double distance=5pt,draw=black] (aa)-- +(0,2);
\draw[thick,double=brown!40,double distance=5pt,draw=black] (A)-- (B) arc(-180:0:1cm) -- (E) ;
\draw[thick,double=white,double distance=5pt,draw=black] (E)-- +(0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]